# What Cantonese verb was spoken on what boyfriends 港女 pick? Sounds like 打鍋?

Tags: cantonese

Context is Maria Cordero asking Lisa Tse Lisa's criteria for picking boyfriends.  At [29:26](https://youtu.be/Fie0v-ec0SQ?t=1766), young female reporter in all black strap dress says something like 打鍋. I don't think this is 鍋. What's second character?

Maria Cordero repeats 打鍋 at [29:30](https://youtu.be/Fie0v-ec0SQ?t=1770) and [29:44](https://youtu.be/Fie0v-ec0SQ?t=1784). She explains this describes [港女](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gong_nui). Cordero says only 港女 aren't afraid say this in front cameras! Cordero makes this sound like bad word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

打鑊 (give a beating) came from a Cantonese slang [打鑊甘](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/57700/)

打 here means 'to beat up' and  鑊 (wok) is a classifier for session/ time/ instance of beating (and other things too)

She said: 想打鑊佢 = 想打他一頓 (want to beat him up)

Other examples of 打鑊:

打你幾鑊 = 打你幾回 (beat you up a few times)

見一鑊打一鑊/ 見鑊打鑊 = 見一回打一回 (beat you up every time I see you)

俾人打鑊 = 被人打一頓 (beat up by someone)

*I like explaining Cantonese slangs because they are fun to say. 想打佢 is not funny at all, unlike 想打鑊佢 (鑊 indicates a substantial amount).*

Comment: thanks. but why 港女 want to 打鑊 their boyfriends?

Comment: It is just a comment about 港女 (Hong Kong's women) are so bold that they dare to use rough language like that